# How to add a tuple to the first position of a list in Python

Tags: javascript, python, google-visualization

I have a list that looks something like this

```
service = build('fusiontables', 'v1', developerKey=API_KEY)
query = "SELECT USStateCode, NOFU2008 FROM " + TABLE_ID
response = service.query().sql(sql=query).execute()
variables = {"data2008": json.encode(response['rows'])}
self.render_response('index.html', variables)
```

I am passing this to JavaScript and using this data to create an intensity map. However, the map requires the first tuple to be headers. So for that I need the data to do something like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'No of Users'],
    ['US-PA', 200],
    ['US-CA', 300],
    ['US-NY', 400],
    ['US-TX', 500],
    ['US-SC', 600],
    ['US-MD', 700]
]);
```

How do I do this? Instead of these hardcoded values I want to use the actual data that I get from data2008. How do I add this to the first position?

Comment: I'm confused -- when are you using Python? All I see is javascript.

Comment: I *think*  the first line is supposed to be Python (Unicode string!), but the `var` was put there by accident.

Comment: @adsmith - I edited the question. I hope this gives a more clear picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert an object at the beginning of a list, you can use [`list.insert`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#mutable-sequence-types). The link is to the docs for mutable sequence methods, a `list` being a mutable sequence (as opposed to a `str` which is a sequence but not mutable)

```
data = [[u'US-AL', 290060.0], [u'US-AK', 46400.0], [u'US-AZ', 320320.0]]
data.insert(0,('State','No of users'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert it into the first position:

```
my_list.insert(0, ('this', 'is', 'a', 'tuple'))
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to add a `tuple` to the first position of a `list` in Python?

Here's a `list`:

```
>>> my_list = list('abc')
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Insert a `tuple` at the beginning (index 0):

```
>>> my_list.insert(0, ())
>>> my_list
[(), 'a', 'b', 'c']
```